# Correct orientation of Okinawan purple sweet potato

Tags: sprouting, sweet-potato

Not being able to find any organic Okinawan purple sweet potatoes in the supermarket, I bought slips online. They’ve been growing for about 9 months and I’ve finally harvested the tubers.

What is the correct orientation to place this tuber into the water, so that I can grow my own slips? I know the general rule is blunt side up and tapered side down, but I think my case will be approximately the same shape on both ends after I snap off the excess ligaments.

One telltale sign is that in the bottom of my photo, you’ll see a stem with a long white root protruding out of it. I think this is the part that was connected to the mother slip. I’m not too sure as I forgot which orientation it was when I dug the tuber out of the soil. When I dug up my next batch, should I pay attention to its orientation while growing and should it remain the same orientation when I attempt to sprout it?

[image]